# How to download aws docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a jupyter notebook locally and would like to use sagemaker docker image , listed here -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-images.html, one i am interested in is Data Science 2.0.
Do download , i'm running following command.

```
docker pull image_uri
```

Based on the example provided, i've tried few , but unsucessful. what is the correct URI
for Base Python 3.0 (resource identifier - sagemaker-base-python-310-v1)?

I've tried few images and was sucessfull to pull down images , but not the ones listed in this . my guess is , I'm not using the right URI format.

Comment: Can you please share complete command that you have tried and also what error is coming?